# array of letters with no two consecutive rows identical

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider a 5×5 array. In how many ways can we fill the array with X-s and O-s so that no two consecutive rows are identical?

So first one we can do $2^5$ ways. Second row in $2^5-1$, the same as 3,4,5 rows.

**So final answer is $2^5*(2^5-1)^4$**

Is it correct way of thinking?

Comment: It should be a product not sum, i.e. $2^5(2^5-1)^4$.

Comment: i think, due to rotational symmetry, it is overcounted

Comment: @AnuragA Yeah, sorry my bad.

Comment: @Kiran So how would you solve this task?

Comment: @sswwqqaa, i am also thinking in the same way.  i am checking with a small example whether your answer is right.

Comment: @Kiran what do you mean by rotational symmetry? It is an array so the first row and fifth row cannot be thought of as consecutive.

Comment: for a , 2×2 array, due to a rotation of 90 degree, whether $\left[
    \begin{array}{c c|c}
      X&O\\
      O&X
    \end{array}\right] 
\left[
    \begin{array}{c c|c}
      O&X\\
      X&O
    \end{array}\right]$ are same?

Comment: I don't think that this interpretation holds in the present context. But I will let OP chime in on this.